# Azure VM Created with Wrong User Name

Tags: azure, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, virtual-machine, userid

I decided to try creating a SharePoint Dev environment in Azure. I logged onto the Azure portal and chose to create a new VM using the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate template from the gallery and after several minutes, this machine showed as being created and I logged on using my credentials.

However, when I open Visual Studio on the new machine, the splash screen shows the user erica.merchant@xxxxxx.com. No big deal, I 'log off' visual studio and then tell it I would like to log on using a different ID and it allows me to log on using my ID and updates the VS license using my ID.

All is good. Until I try to open PowerShell to run a script. My prompt is showing C:\users\ericame instead of using my userid.

My question: How did I end up with some other user on my box? Has anyone else experienced this? How do I correct it?